# HSQLDB 2.3.3 database properties file

Tags: hsqldb

I am new to hsqldb and I am trying to upgrade an existing hsqldb database server from version 1.8 to 2.3.3. I want to copy the database properties from old db.properties to the new one, but it gets overwritten everytime I restart the db server. I have tried setting the db properties using sql commands but it does not show up in the new db.properties file. Please tell me how to set properties for the hsqldb database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HSQLDB does not store the general database settings in the `.properties` files. Instead, it stores the settings as a series of `SET ...` statements in the `.script` file. The relevant properties of the old database are converted to the new settings when you upgrade.

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/management-chapt.html#mtc_database_settings

Comment: Then how come when I open the properties file of my older version database I can see all the properties there, is there a way I can confirm the older properties are converted to new settings. Also if I want to add a new database property how can I do that.

Comment: The older version is 7 years old and stored the properties that way. The current version is different. See the HSQLDB Guide.

Comment: @fredt, if you have a minute, I'm getting a pesky error when using HSQLDB and setting the `DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_ALLOW_EMPTY_FIELDS` property. I've posted a fully functional example in my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41471468/error-setting-database-config-property-for-idatabaseconnection-hsqldb). Thank you kindly.