# Error setting database config property for IDatabaseConnection (HSQLDB)

Tags: postgresql, unit-testing, integration-testing, hsqldb, dbunit

I've included fully testable code below, which generates the following error when supplied with a dataset `xml` containing empty fields. A sample `dataset.xml` is also below.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: table.column=places.CITY value is
>   empty but must contain a value (to disable this feature check, set
>   DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_ALLOW_EMPTY_FIELDS to true)

The thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40629855/3851150) is similar but is different since it uses multiple `dbTester.getConnection()` whereas my code only uses one, yet has the same error. The main problem relates to this line `databaseConfig.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_ALLOW_EMPTY_FIELDS, Boolean.TRUE);` .
 It seems to be ignored entirely. I've tried putting the `init` code inside the `@Test` method but the error remains.

**dataset.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<dataset>
  <places address="123 Up Street" city="Chicago" id="001"/>
  <places address="456 Down Street" city="" id="002"/>
  <places address="789 Right Street" city="Boston" id="003"/>
</dataset>
```

**Code:**

```
import org.dbunit.IDatabaseTester;
import org.dbunit.JdbcDatabaseTester;
import org.dbunit.database.DatabaseConfig;
import org.dbunit.database.IDatabaseConnection;
import org.dbunit.dataset.IDataSet;
import org.dbunit.dataset.xml.FlatXmlDataSetBuilder;
import org.dbunit.operation.DatabaseOperation;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class DBConnectionIT {
    IDatabaseTester databaseTester = null;
    IDatabaseConnection iConn = null;
    Connection connection = null;

    @Before
    public void init() throws Exception {
        databaseTester = new JdbcDatabaseTester(org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.class.getName(), "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb;sql.syntax_pgs=true", "sa", "");
        iConn = databaseTester.getConnection();
        DatabaseConfig databaseConfig = iConn.getConfig();
        databaseConfig.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_ALLOW_EMPTY_FIELDS, Boolean.TRUE);
        connection = iConn.getConnection();
        createTable(connection);
        IDataSet dataSet = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(new File("dataset.xml"));
        databaseTester.setDataSet(dataSet);
        databaseTester.setSetUpOperation(DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT);
        databaseTester.setTearDownOperation(DatabaseOperation.DELETE_ALL);
        databaseTester.onSetup();
    }

    @Test
    public void testDBUnit() {
        try {
            PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement("select * from places");
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void createTable(Connection conn) throws Exception {
        PreparedStatement pp = conn.prepareStatement(
                "CREATE TABLE PLACES" +
                        "(address VARCHAR(255), " +
                        "city TEXT, " +
                        "id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL primary key)");
        pp.executeUpdate();
        pp.close();
    }
}
```

---

### EDIT (based on César Rodríguez's answer):

I've now refactored out this method in the parent class:

```
 protected void setUpDatabaseConfig(DatabaseConfig databaseConfig) {
        databaseConfig.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_ALLOW_EMPTY_FIELDS, Boolean.TRUE);
    }
```

and created a sub-class which `@Overrides` this method, but it's saying this sub-class is not being used. How do I address this class (DBConnectionOverride) in the parent class, to solve my problem?

```
class DBConnectionOverride extends DBConnectionIT {
    @Override
    protected void setUpDatabaseConfig(DatabaseConfig databaseConfig) {
        databaseConfig.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_ALLOW_EMPTY_FIELDS, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Look carefully at the question you linked to. It looks like you need to use iConn as the connection after setting the FEATURE_ALLOW_EMPTY_FIELDS property. No call to iConn.getConnection() seems to be required.

Comment: @fredt, thanks for the feedback. I'm confused why you'd say that `No call to iConn.getConnection() seems to be required` since the prepared statements require a `Connection` not a `IDatabaseConnection`. If I simply pass in `IDatabaseConnection.getConnection()` within those prepare statements, it returns the same error. Can you implement your suggestions into the code base I've provided? I'm at a complete loss

Comment: It's always this line causing the error: `databaseTester.onSetup();`

Comment: @Nova I can't use your example. I just provide you my way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've stumbled upon the correct answer, at least the one which solves my problem. It related to this line all along `databaseTester.onSetup()` which could simply be replaced with `DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(iConn, dataSet);`. Feel free comment on why this seemed to have fixed the error.

Comment: Did you ever look at this again? I can see in the logging the DbUnit is getting an iConn and setting the config with `FEATURE_ALLOW_EMPTY_FIELDS` = true, but then initializing it along with several other features to false. Looks like a bug to me but my analysis doesn't make sense if this works for you....

Comment: I traced the error to `DataSourceDatabaseTester` which instantiates a new `DatabaseConnection` on each `getConnection()` call, and there's the rub - if you call `DatabaseTester.onSetup()`, it will be fed a new instance of `DatabaseConnection` which creates for itself a new instance of `DatabaseConfig` in the constructor, thus ignoring any `DatabaseConfig` instance which you initialised with `ALLOW_EMPTY_FIELDS`. Bug? Not sure. Was obviously never made to be configured this way. The only place this config is used in DbUnit's Ant-related code. Think I'll have to visit dbunit-user ML.

Answer (score 0):

You must override method setUpDatabaseConfig(DatabaseConfig config) as follows:

```
@Override
protected void setUpDatabaseConfig(DatabaseConfig config) {
    config.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_ALLOW_EMPTY_FIELDS, true); 
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @César, but I'm confused where to put this `@Override` exactly. Could you show me what the final code should look like using my code provided? I've extracted the line `databaseConfig.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_ALLOW_EMPTY_FIELDS, Boolean.TRUE);` into a method like your code suggests, and then I put your `@Override` method in the subclass, but it's telling me that my subclass (which I've named DBConnectionOverride) is not being used anywhere. I've edited my question to show this... what's wrong?

Comment: I think you can put the override method just in your `DBConnectionIT` class. Anyway if you want to create a new class like `DBConnectionOverride`, this class should not extends `DBConnectionIT` class. It is the `DBConnectionIT` class that extends `DBConnectionOverride`

Comment: That doesn't work, if the superclass extends the sub-class, then the `@Override` method returns this error `method does not override method from its superclass`. This error disappears if the subclass `extends` the superclass, however then the subclass becomes grayed out (not used). If you can get it to work using the code I provided in the question, and then share it here, I'll award you the +1.

Comment: I seemed to have solved my own problem without using `Override` at all. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

for me it's work:

```
        IDatabaseConnection dbConn = new DatabaseDataSourceConnection(getDataSource());
        dbConn.getConfig().setProperty(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_ALLOW_EMPTY_FIELDS, true);
        DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(dbConn, getiDataSet(loadDBData.source()));
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your results when using `DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(iConn, dataSet);` in my context. Are you able to provide a solution using my provided codebase? I'll give you the checkmark if so. Thanks!

Comment: It's always this line causing the error: `databaseTester.onSetup();`